# UnicodeDecodeError when starting Gramps

Tags: 14.04, python

Today I tried to start Gramps but it fails with an`UnicodeDecodeError` and exits:

```
$ gramps
2017-02-18 19:09:05.715: ERROR: grampsgui.py: line 384: 
Gramps failed to start. Please report a bug about this.
This could be because of an error in a (third party) View on startup.
To use another view, don't load a Family Tree, change view, and then load your Family Tree.
You can also change manually the startup view in the gramps.ini file 
by changing the last-view parameter.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gui/grampsgui.py", line 353, in __startgramps
    Gramps(argparser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gui/grampsgui.py", line 252, in __init__
    from . import viewmanager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gui/viewmanager.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .plug import tool
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gui/plug/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ._guioptions import make_gui_option, add_gui_options
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gui/plug/_guioptions.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .. import widgets
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gui/widgets/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .dateentry import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gui/widgets/dateentry.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .monitoredwidgets import MonitoredDate
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gui/widgets/monitoredwidgets.py", line 57, in <module>
    from gramps.gen.datehandler import displayer, parser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gen/datehandler/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from ._datehandler import (LANG, LANG_SHORT, LANG_TO_PARSER, LANG_TO_DISPLAY,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gen/datehandler/_datehandler.py", line 48, in <module>
    from ._dateparser import DateParser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gen/datehandler/_dateparser.py", line 53, in <module>
    from . import _grampslocale
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gen/datehandler/_grampslocale.py", line 217, in <module>
    to_uni(time.strftime('%A',(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1)), codeset), # Wednesday
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gramps/gen/constfunc.py", line 67, in conv_to_unicode
    return x if x is None or isinstance(x, UNITYPE) else cuni(x, y) if y else cuni(x)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried to run it with another value as `LANGUAGE` environment variable but it doesn't work.

Gramps version is 4.0.4-1, Python 2.7.6, Ubuntu 14.04.

I can't do a backup because the GUI won't load and creating the backup via console fails with the same error, so I don't want to risk doing an update without having a proper backup.

What can I do to run Gramps, or at least diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround:

```
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 gramps
```